# Disable company in eshell when using TRAMP

Tags: company-mode, tramp, eshell

`company-mode` is awesome. It even works in Eshell. However, when I'm `cd`d into another host, company mode makes Eshell unusable because it's always hanigng waiting for TRAMP.

Is there any way I can enable `company-mode` in Eshell, but only when the current directory is local?

Comment: [Bug filed](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/396).

Answer (score 1):

The nuclear option worked for me after this behavior finally drove me around the bend while typing tramp filenames.

```
  ;; disable company completion of *all* remote filenames, whether   
  ;; connected or not
  (defun company-files--connected-p (file)
    (not (file-remote-p file)))
```

Comment: Do you know of any side-effects of using this?

Comment: No; all's well so far... It seems that the worst case would be messed-up company completion of filenames.  Maybe there's a way to disable that bit of company.

Comment: Hm... `company` still completes things like command names for me, and that is actually the more annoying lag. (I don't always type file paths, but I always type commands)